# how do you use a string in a while loop and then number the string?

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop

in my intro to programming class. I am supposed to make a program that asks the user to enter his/her name and then use a while loop to print the name in the following manner:

*(user entered Caroline)*

1. C
2. a
3. r
4. o
5. l
6. i
7. n
8. e

Caroline, there are 8 letters in your first name.

--I've tried a bunch of things but still can't figure it out.--[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi28i.png)

Comment: What did you try? Do update your post with that as well as the error you encountered.

Comment: what have you done so far? what language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are correctly getting the user entered string from the STDIN.

You may look to do something like this in your language of choice:

1. Find the length of your string
2. Use the while loop, with the condition relating to the length of your string, to move through the string character by character
3. Print out to a newline each individual character in your string

**Feel free to ask questions and I would be happy to elaborate. Adding some examples of your code so far and the problems your facing would be useful.**

Answer (score 0):

In C++, this would be:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int i=0;
  string s;
  cin>>s;
  while(i<s.length())
  { cout<<i+1<<"."<<cout<<s[i]<<endl;
    i++;
  }
cout<<s<<", "<<"There are "<<s.length()<<" letters in your first name.";
return 0;
}
```

This is also very similar in Java, you should be able to derive it looking at this if you expected it in a programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

inside your main method try this:

```
    //Asks user name.
    System.out.println("What's your name?");

    //Instantiates scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //With the scanner it reads user input and save it in the variable name
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    //It is a good programming practice to close the scanner
    sc.close();

    /*The loop that for each letter of the name also prints the position
    number plus 1*/
    int i = 0;
    while (i < name.length()) {

        System.out.println(i+1 + ". " + name.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per snap shot shared by OP:

[image: OP snap shot]

Here, you need to modify this lines:

```
System.out.println(name.charAt(i));
```

to

```
System.out.printf("%d. %c%n",(1+i),name.charAt(i));
```

Also, change this line:

```
  i++;
}}}
```

to

```
  i++;
}
System.out.printf("%s, there are %d letters in your first name%n",name,i));
}}
```